# Distribution of $\epsilon(X+Y) + \gamma(X+Z)$ with $\epsilon, \gamma\sim{\mathcal U}(0,1/2)$

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

I wish to calculate the distribution for the following combination of random variables
$$\epsilon(X+Y) + \gamma(X+Z)$$
Where $\epsilon$ and $\gamma$ are random variables drawn from an uniform distribution from $0$ to $1/2$ and $X,Y,Z$ are random variables with distribution $\mathcal P$.
Moreover, $\epsilon$ and $\gamma$ are independent of each other and independent of $X,\,Y,\,Z$.

The problem that I am facing is how to take care of the fact that $(X+Y)$ and $(X+Z)$ both have $X$ into it, implying they are not independent.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to group into $(\epsilon + \gamma)X + \epsilon Y + \gamma Z$ ?

Comment: Yes but then $\epsilon,\gamma$ stay and make the individual terms dependent.

Comment: @Sayan Are $\epsilon$ and $\gamma$ independent of each other and also independent of $X, Y, Z$? If so, you should state that. Assuming they are, you can condition on $\epsilon$ and $\gamma$, find the distribution of the linear combination of $X, Y, Z$ and then integrate over the uniform distribution. This could be tractable if ${\cal P}$ was normal or at least had a known closed form. I doubt that it's possible to derive a closed-form expression for arbitrary ${\cal P}$.

Comment: Yes they are independent. I have also included it in the query.